# BrE usage of "should have"

Tags: british-english, transatlantic-differences, should

This usage of "should have" appears to be a Britishism. I wonder if anyone cares to provide an explanation of the British "should have" usages.

> Several observers have emphasised Dusty Miller's devotion to the Joyita and reported his insistence that the boat was unsinkable. Why, then, would he willingly have abandoned ship under any circumstances? According to Robin Maugham, Charles Marsack said, "**I can't imagine why he should have left her**. And I don't believe he did." (source: *Joyita: Solving the Mystery* 2002)

The passage deals with [MV Joyita's 1955 disappearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MV_Joyita). Miller clearly is believed to have abandoned the boat, so "should have left" here does not indicate a wish contrary to what happened in the past, rather, a confirmation of what happened. Why "should have left"? What sense of should is invoked? Here's another similar sentence:

> What puzzles me is why he should have left without telling me. (source: Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I wouldn't say that this usage is common here in Australia, but it seems perfectly natural to me. (We are more aligned with British English than American in general though.)

Comment: "should have" is not always British English. That said, I personally, am having a hard time trying to figure out when I would or would not use it as an AmE speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence *I can't imagine why he should have left her* expresses a personal judgement or reaction to a behaviour.

In the entry on *should* in *Practical English Usage* (page 512) Swan states in the section titled *reactions: It's surprising that she should...*:

> *Should* is also used in subordinate clauses after words expressing personal judgements and reactions, especially to facts which are
>   already known or already mentioned. (This use is more common in
>   British than American English. It is not particularly formal.)

Swan gives the examples:

- It's surprising that she *should* say that to you.
- I'm sorry you *should* think I did it on purpose.
- Do you think it's normal that the child *should* be so tired.

He concludes:

> In American English, *would* is more usual in this kind of sentence:
>   - It was natural that they *would* want him to go to a good school. (BrE...that they *should*...)

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: So this usage is possible only when _should_ is used in a subordinate clause. And this wouldn't work, would it? _Charles Marsack said, "Why should he have left her? And I don't believe he did."_ // Also, in Swan's examples, I wonder why Swan should use (or should have used?) _should say/think/be_ instead of _should have said/thought/been_ when the situation of saying/thinking/being is located prior to the time of speaking.

Comment: @listeneva. As a British English native speaker I use expressions such as: _I should think so!_ or _I should hope not_. So this use of _should_ is not confined to subordinate clauses. The inherent problem with _should_ is that its use can result in ambiguity. The style guide _The Right Word at the Right Time: A Guide to the English Language and How to Use It_ (p560) discusses the sentence: _It was obvious that we should report him to the police_. >>

Comment: >> "Most people would understand this to mean 'it was obvious that we ought to report him'. But a purist might have intended it to mean 'It was obvious that we were going to report him' and thereby have laid himself open to misunderstanding."

Comment: @Shoe Thanks for responding. But I'm afraid you have not answered neither of my questions. Instead, you have given me another question to ask. Could you first please answer the two questions in my prior comment?

Comment: @Shoe And here's my third question arising out of your last comment: Swan says "_Should_ is also used ... after words expressing personal judgements and reactions, especially to facts which are already known or already mentioned." But in neither _I should think so!_ nor _I should hope not_ is _should_ used after words expressing personal judgements and reactions, especially to facts which are already known or already mentioned. So I don't understand how your main-clause examples qualify as examples of Swan's _should_ usage.

Comment: @listeneva. I gave an example of this use of _should_ in a main clause, which was an answer to your first question. And the reference to the _Right Word_ extract  was an implied answer to your second question about "_Why should he have left her_ doesn't work. As to your third question, it seems to me that. e.g. "_I should hope not_" is indeed expressing a reaction and personal judgement. For example, from the Cambridge dictionary: _'She loved the gift.' 'I should think she did - you paid enough for it!'_

Comment: @Shoe Let me get this straight. Re the 1st Q: So you're saying that _Why should he have left her?_ doesn't work in Swan's sense, right?  // Let me rephrase the 2nd Q: Why do you think Swan didn't use the sentence _It's surprising that she should **have said** that to you._? // Re the 3rd Q, I think in Swan's quote, "words expressing personal judgements and reactions" are _surprising_, _sorry_, _normal_, etc. I don't think Swan means that it's the _should_-clause itself that is supposed to express "a reaction and personal judgement". Am I misunderstanding Swan?

Comment: @listeneva. Q1. Yes. Q2. _It's surprising that she should do/have done that_. Both mean the same. The first variation is shorter, and could be considered as following Grice's maxim of quantity. Q3. Possibly, or maybe I am. You might want to turn your enquiries here a new question, to which you could get some more informative answers.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article contains the following: *A friend of Miller, Captain S. B. Brown, was convinced that Miller would never have left Joyita alive*.

Apparently Miller (and everyone else) was missing from the vessel, but there was speculation that he might have been injured and fallen overboard, or that the occupants had been captured. So his leaving voluntarily is not a certainty.

The use of *should* or *would* implies that the speaker cannot imagine a scenario in which it is probable that Miller deliberately abandoned ship.

Comment: I'd have no problem at all if it were "I can't imagine why he _would_ have left her." With "_should_" it seems a totally different story to me. Could you expand on "should have"?

Comment: Cambridge Dictionaries gives '_why should_ when giving or asking the reason for something' as 'mainly UK'. e.g. _I don't see why he should get more money than me._ I gather you are in the USA, so perhaps that's why it puzzles you?

Comment: I guess so. I am surprised this does not appear to have been discussed before. I would think there must have been a canonical post on ELU/ELL. I am also puzzling over the downvote casually hurled at my question. It seems the downvoter just mistook this question to be simply about the third conditional and failed to understand its nature. All the more reason why there should be a detailed answer on "should have" in the BrE. I wonder if you could elaborate further.

Comment: All I can tell you is that I scrolled through Cambridge's various definitions for _should_ until I found one that seemed to fit your sentence. All the ones that say 'mainly UK' seem perfectly natural to me.

Comment: I have also gone through Cambridge's "should" page and understood what's meant by the example sentences, but I still think a detailed answer is in order, considering there isn't one yet. I understood the meaning of the sentence in question before posting but couldn't explain the usage. I still can't except I now know it is a BrE usage. Anyway I will wait and see if more detailed answers come up. Thanks!